# Android: OOP | Using functions in other files

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm pretty new to Android but I have some experience (and a bit rusty with) Java and OOP.

Basically what my app does is when you press a button, led's or "images" will flash.

I'm trying to divide up my project into multiple files where I can just import a java file to use the class's functions but I'm unsure on how to do that...

I have two files.  1) HelloFormStuff.java (this is like the main one), and 2) led_functions.java

In HelloFormStuff I put:

```
import com.example.helloformstuff.led_functions
// com.example.helloformstuff is the package
```

Example of code.. HelloFormStuff.java

```
    public class HelloFormStuff extends Activity {

/* Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            currentMode.setText("Button 1 Pressed");
            led_circleBusy();
           }
    });
}
```

}

And in led_functions.java...

```
public class led_functions extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ImageView LED_1;
    LED_1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.LED_1);

   @Override 
    public void led_circleBusy()
    {
        LED_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
```

}

An error I get is: The method led_circleBusy() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

**So I'm asking is how to implement my other functions from other files.**

Thanks.

-Paul

PS: I've been looking at sample code and if you're wondering why I put something like an "@Override" where it's not needed, just ignore it.. I've been trying random things :l

Comment: Why does `led_functions` extend `Activity`? An Activity is a UI class. Also, you're trying to call a method `led_circleBusy()` on a class which hasn't been instantiated and, as `led_functions` is an Activity and impossible to instantiate from another Activity it isn't going to work anyway. Please see...http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I was just copy-pasta'ing my code from HelloFormStuff not knowing that Activity makes another UI class.

Comment: Apologies for getting your name wrong in my first comment. The best way to approach it is to create a 'helper' class then instantiate it within your Activity - you'll then be able to call methods on it as you need to. You can use pretty much any 'generic' Java class (or POJO) when programming with Android. Just remember that certain classes such as `Activity` play a special/specific part in an Android app.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: Thanks.  Creating the helper class is exactly what I'm trying to do.. just figuring out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following from your `HelloFormStuff` class.

```
led_functions led = new led_functions();
led.led_circleBusy();
```

Then get rid of the `@Override` from above the `led_circleBusy()` method.  You shouldn't really be calling other Activity's methods like that though.  Is `led_functions` really an Activity/UI class?  If not, remove the `extends Activity`, add `LED_1` to `HelloFormStuff` and then pass it as a parameter to `led.led_circleBusy(ImageView led1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I removed the "extends Activity" like you said but now the "    LED_1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.LED_1);
" line doesn't work because it's for the Activity UI Class..

Comment: Right, that's why I mentioned that you should move the handling of LED_1 to your main Activity and then pass it as a parameter to led_circleBusy(..).

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like you'll have to go back studying:

1. Java/OOP
2. Android applications lifecycles

   1. Java/OOP

In Java, you can't define a method inside another method the way you did with led_circleBusy() inside onCreate(). Your led_functions class can't compile as is.

Then, you would have to either declare your led_circleBusy() in order to call it from anywhere using led_functions.led_circleBusy() or create a new instance of led_functions (new led_functions()) before invoking led_circleBusy() on it.

1. Android application lifecycles

Activities in android applications can be considered as "screens". 2 Activities can only communicates via Intents. An action on a View in one Activity can modify a View on a second Activity only by passing an intent from Activity A to Activity B.

If your components are on the same screen, then you should not have 2 subclasses of Activity but only one and a utility class to which you pass parameters from your Activity.

You should read really carefully http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle

And then, read it again.

The second thing you should read carefully in android dev guide is about Intents:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

These concepts are new to any developer, experienced in Java or not. So you have to spend the time necessary for you to understand them in details to be able to create the most basic android app.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all classes (Android specific or otherwise) occupy the same package / namespace, e.g., com.mycompany.mypackage then no imports are necessary...

For the helper...

```
package com.mycompany.mypackage

public class MyHelper {

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }

}
```

For the Activity...

```
package com.mycompany.mypackage

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyHelper helper = new MyHelper();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(...) {
        ...

        helper.doSomething();

}
```

Comment: Alright so this is what I have so far in led_functions.

public class led_functions{
final ImageView LED_1;
LED_1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.LED_1);

But now it has a problem with findViewById (I think since it's not under the Activity UI), and the error is: Return type for the method is missing

Comment: Actually, I got it.  Thanks for the input on the helper class!

Answer (score 0):

HelloFormStuff class has no led_circleBusy() implementation, so this method couldn't be called

Comment: You create a public method named led_circleBusy()... That's also a strange naming convention for a Java app.

Comment: May I ask how to implement it?

Comment: @Ed S. I thought the exact same thing about naming convention, but was too lazy to express it in my answer :-)

Comment: @Ed S. I'm porting this over from an existing C-embedded project and currently using the same names for the file/function names just to keep it readable.

Comment: Naming conventions are the least important errors in this code... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways.

1. Declare the `led_circleBusy()` as static, then you can call it as in `led_functions.led_circleBusy()`
2. Keep it non-static and call it on an instance of `led_functions` as in

   `led_functions lf = new led_functions();
   lf.led_circleBusy();`

This is strictly java-speaking. If they are actually two different `Activity`s (different 'windows') that share nothing, but one calls another, you should take a look at `Intent`s.